# How can I report a broken page to Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to see:

http://www.ibm.com/us/en/sandbox/ver1/

And the menus doesn't work. How can I report it to Google Chrome team?

I have this version of Chrome:

[image]

Comment: You are two versions behind, surely the easiest thing would be just to update chrome? No point reporting something thats been fixed in subsequent releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to view this page in chrome 8, so you may want to update. But this doesn't answer your question. I think they removed the report broken link some time ago.

Edit -  <del>It looks like there is a [forum post](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2a2135b6f50fd524&hl=en) on google support where a bunch of people are posting link and page issues, but not sure how long that is going to last.</del>

Here is the link to submit support issues - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry. They say they want you to use this for a fairly bad bug, so use it wisely.